# Is there a way to generate a report on where my paper was cited within another paper?

Tags: citations, bibliometrics

I do not mean the citations as they come up in Google Scholar, but given a paper that has cited my paper, is there a way to figure out where in their paper they have cited my paper?

The way I do it now is I try to find the reference number to my paper, and then do Ctrl+F to find where it appears in the papers. It could be also something similar to what is being asked [here](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/62884/are-there-any-metrics-considering-how-heavily-cited-a-paper-is-within-another-pa) which helps in finding the impact of a paper within another paper.

Comment: What are you hoping for that is better than that? Are you talking about in PDFs, HTML?

Comment: Your university librarian will be able to tell you what citation list journals exist in your discipline.

Comment: this is too vague. You want to know context around the citation (5 sentences)? You want to know name of the subsection (Intro/Results/Discussion)? You want to know how many references are nearby, i.e. is your citation 1 out of 25 a row?

Comment: What is wrong with the current method?

Comment: Why do you need this info?  Probably it would be more useful to find out how people have used your work, or what they said about your work.  E.g., say a paper with a famous name cited your work, and you want to know whether the famous person said anything good about your work, or rubbishes your work.

Comment: I totally get the purpose of the question. When we update https://dealii.org/publications.html, we want to know which papers that cite ours cite us as "related art" and which actually use the software described in our papers. We only care about the latter category. So I understand why you would want to find the exact context of a citation. But we only do as the OP suggests: Find which reference is ours, then Ctrl-F to that number, and read the context. Having a tool do that for us would be fabulous.

Comment: In my field, it could happen that your citation gets buried in an aggregate citation, for example "A number of previous papers [1-8] deal with X". In that case, CTRL-F would not do the trick - you would need to visually scan the article.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [scite](https://scite.ai/) does something very similar to what you're asking for. Note that they have different tiers, and the free tier is fairly limited.

Comment: ResearchGate does this as well (generally for free, although there are some concerns about it).

Comment: @lighthousekeeper Is there a way to see the context of all citations to a paper with RG? I've only seen it show context for the first recognized citation.