# How to automatically extract references from pdf by number of occurrence?

Tags: citations

I'm looking for software that allows me to extract citations from a pdf article and the number of occurrences of each citation. I'm looking to use this as a (admittedly very imperfect) proxy to estimate what citations a paper is based on.

In case it matters, the citation style the papers are using is mostly APA.

I'm using scite.ai now but it's not getting the job done in a satisfactory way because it miscounts the number of times a reference has been cited. I would also prefer a free option if that exists.

If there is a better heuristic to estimate which citations a paper is primarily based on (which can be automated), I'm also interested. But perhaps that's a topic for a new question.

Comment: How do you determine which citations are 'primary' and which are not? The raw number of times a given paper is actually cited in another paper may not be a good indicator.

Comment: I know. But it's a starting point no? Location might be another heuristic with citations appearing in the beginning of an article being more important than those later in the article.

Comment: Related, though doesn't cover the number of occurrences: [Retrieving the references in a publication automatically](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/15596/retrieving-the-references-in-a-publication-automatically?rq=1)

Comment: You might want to look into bibliometrics, the study of citations and impacts of articles. Bibliometrics is its own field entirely.

Comment: Related: [Are there any metrics considering how heavily cited a paper is within another paper?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/62884/17254), [Is there a way to generate a report on where my paper was cited within another paper?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/176013/17254) The answer posted for the latter only mentions scite...